# Rosrun can not find an executable file

Tags: ros-melodic, rosrun

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So I have a package called dijkstra, it contains a cpp program in the src folder called algorithm_1.cpp which I need to run.

First I run the command source devel/setup.bash to set up the environment. After that I do, rosrun dijkstra and press tab twice, but it doesn't find any executable file.

This is the CMake-

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(dijkstra)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
roscpp
rospy
geometry_msgs
)

include_directories(include ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} src/algorithm_1.cpp)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}
${catkin_LIBRARIES}
)
```

EDIT-

This is the error I get -

```
parth@Parth:~/catkin_ws/src$ rosrun dijkstra dijkstra.cpp
[rosrun] Couldn't find executable named dijkstra.cpp below /home/parth/catkin_ws/src/dijkstra
[rosrun] Found the following, but they're either not files,
[rosrun] or not executable:
[rosrun]   /home/parth/catkin_ws/src/dijkstra/src/dijkstra.cpp
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/339906/rosrun-can-not-find-an-executable-file./) by [Parth2851](https://answers.ros.org/users/48975/parth2851/) on ROS Answers with karma: 63 on 2019-12-13

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-12-15**:
@rubicks: it would also have worked if you would've updated your answer.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Change name of your main source code file `algorithm_1.cpp` to `dijkstra.cpp`. Use the same name for both executable and source file which is a convention used by many people. Although they don't have to be same as you can see [here](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/CMakeLists.txt). So try this:

```
...
add_executable(dijkstra src/dijkstra.cpp)

target_link_libraries(dijkstra
${catkin_LIBRARIES}
)
...
```

Compile your workspace, source your `.bashrc` and you're good to go.

Also check the `CMakeLists.txt` given [here](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28c%2B%2B%29) for other mistakes if you're still unable to run your node.

---

Originally posted by [mbd](https://answers.ros.org/users/26651/mbd/) with karma: 13 on 2019-12-13

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Parth2851](https://answers.ros.org/users/48975/parth2851/) on 2019-12-14**:
I did this however, there is still an error. I ran `source ~/.bashrc` and `catkin_make` before this. Also, the package name in Package.xml is dijkstra so I really don't know what to do.
`rosrun dijkstra dijkstra [rospack] Error: package 'dijkstra' not found`

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> it contains a cpp program in the src folder called algorithm_1.cpp which I need to run.

this would appear to be the cause of your problem: `.cpp` files are not programs. They are source files which must be compiled into binaries first before they can be executed.

Specifying a `.cpp` file as the `type` of a `node` element in a `.launch` file will not work.

> ```
> project(dijkstra)    
> ...
> add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} src/algorithm_1.cpp)
> ```

`dijkstra.cpp` is the *source file*, not the name of the binary (ie: the compiled program). That would be `dijkstra`.

If you remove the `.cpp` from the `type` attribute of the `node` element in your `.launch` file, things will probably start working (assuming the rest of the `.launch` file is correct).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-12-15

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2